# Использование пакета java.util.concurrent для чтения-записи через буфер.

Tags: многопоточность, java

Как организовать чтение данных(по одному объекту) из файла одним потоком  и через объект-буфер передавать второму потоку, который будет помещать данные в БД. Интересует именно структура организации потоков. Какие объекты из вышеуказанного пакета java.util.concurrent необходимо использовать, как организовать синхронизированный доступ этих потоков к объекту-буфферу имеющему методы readBuffer и writeBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал два треды 2 типов.

Тред который пишет в БД

```
public class WriterThread extends Thread {
  private ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue<DbObject> = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue queue<DbObject>();
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      DbObject obj = queue.peek();
      if(obj!=null) {
        boolean result = writeToDb(obj);
        if(result) queue.poll();
      } else { // в буфере пусто, ждем
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      }
    }
  }
  public void add(DbObject obj) { queue.add(obj);}
}
```

Тред, который читает из файла (их может быть несколько для чтения из разных файлов).
Просто в цикле читает из файла объекты и вызывает add(DbObject)

Comment: Ответ хороший, но в задаче имеются ограничения на использование в качестве буффера коллекций и sleep();

Answer (score 1):

без каких либо коллекций и дополнительных "буферов":

```
    // поток который будет непрерывно считывать поток данных из файла
    class FileReader extends Thread {
        private DbWriter listener = null;
    public FileReader(DbWriter writer) {
        setWriter(writer);
    }

    protected DbWriter getWriter() {
        return listener;
    }

    private void setWriter(DbWriter listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void read() {
        // считываем данные из файла в какую-то переменную
        Object data = null;

        getWriter().handleData(data);
    }
}

// класс который отвечает за сохранение данных в СУБД
abstract class DbWriter {
    // в принцыпе если время вставки соизмеримо по времени с временем чтения или меньше
    // то данный лок не нужен. с другой стороны если важен строгий порядок вставки данных
    // от этот механизм синхронизации лучше оставить
    private Object dataLock = new Object();

    public boolean handleData(Object data) {
        synchronized (dataLock) {
            return handleDataImpl(data);
            }
        }

        protected abstract boolean handleDataImpl(Object data);
    }
```

в качестве буфера выступает "Object data", - который должен быть нужного вам типа для того чтоб хранить отдельную порцию данных (напр. 1 строчку считанную из файла)

p.s. если использование concurrent пакета обязательно условие, можете его использовать для того, чтоб синхронизировать вызовы метода "`DbWriter.handleData`"
    введите код здесь